# Android Studio java mail attachments

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gmail-api

I want to send attachments via javamail api using this code.

I found the code for this class, but I don't know how to call it from MainActivity. I'm a new developer on Android studio.I have given permission in mainfest.xml Please let me know what I am doing wrong and what need to be implemented.Any help is much appreciated.  Unable to attach a file with that as email attachment.

SendEmail.class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class SendEmail {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //authentication info
        final String username = "........@gmail.com";
        final String password = "........";
        String fromEmail = "........@gmail.com";
        String toEmail = "......gmail.com";

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username,password);
            }
        });
        //Start our mail message
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        try {
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmail));
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmail));
            msg.setSubject("Subject Line");

            Multipart emailContent = new MimeMultipart();

            //Text body part
            MimeBodyPart textBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            textBodyPart.setText("My multipart text");

            //Attachment body part.
            MimeBodyPart pdfAttachment = new MimeBodyPart();
            pdfAttachment.attachFile("/home/parallels/Documents/docs/javamail.pdf");

            //Attach body parts
            emailContent.addBodyPart(textBodyPart);
            emailContent.addBodyPart(pdfAttachment);

            //Attach multipart to message
            msg.setContent(emailContent);

            Transport.send(msg);
            System.out.println("Sent message");
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

MainActivity;

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//there must be a code here


    }
}
```

Comment: https://javatutorial.net/send-email-with-attachments-android this link can help you

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to do it using api.

Comment: ok sorry my bad https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_send_email_with_attachment.htm check out this link